# Notification app for beacon

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, eddystone

I am looking for a simple app (preferably for iPhone, but if not then for Android), which pops up a message when it receives a signal from a beacon.
The beacon is a Sensoro 4AA, we only purchased it for demonstration purposes.
The idea is: once we turn the smartphone's bluetooth on, the beacon is detected and the message just pops up.

Is there such an app (as simple as can be), where I can just insert the beacon's details (uuid, addtess, or whatever is needed) and maybe some text or link, in order to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beacon Simulator for Creating, broadcasting and Scanning Beacons as per your needs and testing.

For Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.alea.beaconsimulator
For iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/noteacons-beacon-simulator/id1136196655?mt=8 or https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropbeacon-a-beacon-simulator-for-development-purposes/id866760594?mt=8

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: thank you, I will definitely give it a try, and let you know the result.